# Is there any bank that issues free ATM cards and accounts in Cambodia?

Tags: money

Is there any bank that issues free ATM cards and accounts in Cambodia?

Hello,

I am looking for a bank in Phnom Penh that can set up a bank account for me and preferably a free ATM card to if possible. If not Visa or Mastercard then perhaps a Union Pay card.

Is there a bank like that here?

Vesa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to travel

Comment: I found it very useful.

Comment: Using an ATM locally is a typical thing travellers do. Making an ATM card saves money while travelling sometimes too.

Comment: @Vesa Yes, but a traveler uses an ATM from their home country, not opening a local bank account to get an ATM card. How long do you plan to stay in Cambodia?

Answer (score 2):

[ABA Bank](https://www.ababank.com/) does this. They are fairly ubiquitous locally and have a number of branches in Phnom Penh. I opened an account with them in 2013 as a foreigner. They required my passport, proof of accommodation (my hotel booking was fine) and my visitor visa (I believe it was 3 months).

If I remember correctly, you can choose between a free ATM card and a non-free Mastercard. I believe the Mastercard is ~25 USD a year and works overseas. The ATM one only works locally. They have internet banking that is functional (but not really pretty) and works from overseas. They have a token generator (that they call a "machine") that you can use to access your internet banking from anywhere in the world.

Do note that they do NOT ship card / token generator replacements outside of Cambodia and you'll need to go back to the branch to get your card.